# accurate points of Line in Canvas

Tags: canvas, uwp

I am working with UWP
I hava a canvas and I want to draw a line in it.
when I draw the line, the lina dosen't appers  in  the points that I gave. 
it appers in the end of the canvas instead at the center.
I understood that I have to do some transform, but I don't know how to do it.
my code :

```
 line = new Line();
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    line.StrokeThickness = 3;
    line.X1 = 640;
    line.Y1 = 5;
    line.X2 = 320;
    line.Y2 = 50;         
    Canvas.SetLeft(line, line.X1);
    Canvas.SetTop(line, line.Y1);
    this.myCanvas.Children.Add(line);
```

thank you

Comment: What happens when you don't `SetLeft(...)` and `SetTop(...)`?

Comment: it worked thank you